# Sql server (Service) doesn't start

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I removed old sql server from PC. Then I installed new sql server. After this sql server service doesn't start. When I am running service from sql server config manager - I receive error msg:

> "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely
>   fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for
>   details."

this command: ***sqlservr.exe -s MSSQL -e C:\1.txt*** returned logs:

```
2017-05-09 18:32:55.05 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
    Apr 29 2016 23:23:58 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 6.3 <X64> (Build 10586: )

2017-05-09 18:32:55.05 Server      UTC adjustment: 3:00
2017-05-09 18:32:55.05 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2017-05-09 18:32:55.05 Server      All rights reserved.
2017-05-09 18:32:55.05 Server      Server process ID is 7956.
2017-05-09 18:32:55.05 Server      System Manufacturer: 'ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.', System Model: 'X550JX'.
2017-05-09 18:32:55.06 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2017-05-09 18:32:55.06 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\1.txt'.
2017-05-09 18:32:55.06 Server      The service account is 'USER-PC\User'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-05-09 18:32:55.06 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "MSSQL"
     -e "C:\1.txt"
2017-05-09 18:32:55.06 Server      Error: 17113, Severity: 16, State: 1.

2017-05-09 18:32:55.06 Server      Error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.) occurred while opening file 'master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them if necessary.
2017-05-09 18:32:55.07 Server      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
```

I tried to add permissions for **windows user**, **local system** and **local service** but it didn't help.

Comment: few troubleshoting steps i would do 1.) run procmon to see more details on path ,it is expecting 2.) try attaching a windbg and try starting again 3.) may be your installation is botched, you may want to check installation log file and eventvwr as well for any infp

Comment: `USER-PC\User` What type of permissions did you add? Is this user a `Local Admin` and have `SA` rights to the instance `MSSQL`?

Comment: `USER-PC\User` is admin on this machine. I added all permissions to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server`.

Comment: **_>have SA rights to the instance MSSQL?_** - I don't know. How I can check this ?

Comment: When you installed SQL Server, did you add `USER-PC\User` to the list of admins?

Comment: Have you tried starting it with just `-f` parameter?

Comment: yes, I added USER-PC\User to the list of admins

Comment: nope, I didn't try to start with `-f` parameter. I will try now

Comment: hmmm... I have error: `Your SQL Server installation is either corrupt or has been tampered with (Error getting instance ID from name.). Please uninstall then re-run setup to correct this problem`. Interesting, I tried to uninstall and install 2 times.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not on-topic on Stack Overflow. It should probably be asked on [servervfault](https://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

The error log gives you the information about the failure: Error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.) occurred while opening file 'master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error.
You should check your startup parameters.
Start Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services -> your instance -> Properties -> Advanced -> Startup Parameters.
It should contain paths to master.mdf, mastlog.ldf and errorlog

Comment: This tab is empty. Can I add paths manually or need something else ?

Comment: Yes you can, you should enter manually the right paths to 3 file mentioned above, here I copy the parameters filled up with the default paths: -dC:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf;-eC:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG;-lC:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf